# Plotting spatial data on individual map using altair

Tags: python, altair, streamlit

I want to plot spatial data on a map. I want to use `streamlit` because it seems to be easy to use and I want to explore it a bit.
First a tried plotting my data with their inbuilt `deck_gl`-API. This worked pretty good, but since I need to plot glyphs/icons and the `IconLayer` isn't built into `streamlit` yet, I need to switch to another library.

I've read that `Altair` should be a good fit for me and it's also well supported by `streamlit`.
However, I can't figure out how to create a visualization with `altair` when I don't use one of the `vega_datasets`.

My data is in a dataframe with the following structure:

```
|   latitude   |   longitude   |   temperature   |  
| ------------ | ------------- | --------------- |  
| -122.23123   | 38.2321       | 23              | 
| -122.2321    | 28.2342       | 25              |
```

**How can I create a plot like this using altair?**

Any help or hints are highly appreciated!

[image: San Francisco Bay water Temperature plot]

Comment: Vega datasets return either pandas dataframes, or URLs to data stored as JSON records, CSV, or TSV. If you have your data in one of these formats, you can use altair the same way as in the examples.

Comment: Thank you for your input but I'm having a hard time figuring out how my data should look like to get the Altair plot working. Most examples tend to use this dataset `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vega/vega-datasets/master/data/us-10m.json` but its quite difficult for me to figure out how to get my data into a form that works out for Altair. I'm also unable to find examples on how somebody did this before.

Comment: That is a TopoJSON file that contains the boundaries of US states to be plotted behind the data. You can use any TopoJSON file you would like to customize the background map.

Comment: But I should add: if you're looking for a solution where you plug some lat/lon points into a chart, and the renderer will automatically populate the background map in that location with city and county names and boundaries, Altair is not the charting package you're looking for. You might try something like folium: https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/.

Comment: Thank you for your information. Seems like there isn't an easy solution ready where it's able to use Streamlit to create a geospatial plot with icons since it doesn't support folium either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have a pandas DataFrame with a latitude and longitude column then you can use the `latitude` and `longitude` encoding channels in Altair. Here an example using the vega_datasets (it looks like your data).

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

df = data.airports()
df = df[df.state=='TX']
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

```py
df.head()
```

[image: table]

```py
alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(
    latitude='latitude',
    longitude='longitude',
    color='index'
)
```

[image: chart]

Note: Make sure your `latitude` and `longitude` data is in WGS-84 (EPSG:4326) projection.

To add a basemap to your data is a bit hard at the moment. I'm sure somebody will come up with a good approach with the new [image mark](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/image.html) in Vega-lite (to be included in Altair 4), since there is already a working proof-of-concept in Vega ([issue](https://github.com/vega/vega/issues/1212), [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/gist/7b9875a80b2c6ddc404652efcf146126/vega_basemap_image.json)) and in Vega-Lite ([issue](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/5758), [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAdxoATemgAsABh1L4NMlm16lSBpjYQaALzhoQsuQ6U4katTVlk0oKzho+iBMbNhsCEFKgnAAZphRIABORiaoOgC+bkhJSAgQaADaoLJ5DuiYAB6KIHCVOEmOqhowBABMIFklZY6YAJ41dQ2OhsaY7Z0K3QjlILZsEQD6DXBQNBCuIMRIggzlAGyUAOxKTN5qfiDeOJaOuT6bCN5obUrI1ahtwRCYcIHplAAjBkuk4eugkmEkL8ABo1ba7cr8CQAZlO50u11uEKQDxqT3kqH4gIAHMF3mhSd9fv8dECQVMwTNHFA4LJfkkAJrwnZ7NBiV4hDGoUBYhI4vFvZ5E-bkpAfWVKH5-IKUHRiBnTWZMJAbAAqNBiAGU7JsEXzPmJ9qDSsyKoa4ABVJKCHmIkbYPCEAhUTAOyhsHBsn5JOBwTDIHABpJkAiTLWOeYRQb1RroVmGgAUSYQy1Daw2AEp40zZn6YhAAMJsBjslPDdA4NjKTOvHPFm3gkDluAm+z1tMhXVwA3G00AKibLbbC1zKwLcH47ZLttm71HcAKSiGg4zgkz70zoywCma9ELBB7fbgAAIANSAjuM1eOHUbAAKbG8CW3qcc3lIJJMEzAByBo2EkVY-TkECFEKfQdAAXSfBN0C8GgB0cTNMzfOBP2-eDEIfMkLxRWVxx7Ksa3ZFDS0cLxMPQWJBAWJJM3Q2iXzQ6pfwbZJqLUbDmNY9iaBoQt+A4iiHWvTiuzUSRJEYkBsMBIQ2DITNMFxHDh3w9lCkBRDx3fABJAgqULe8b0BAgoGsXSPy-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-W0v1SBmmHylkJ7BEOgZRpTtOM5ABLs9zkB8-ZOhoRoEulTLtAK8EKulAFnbk9T9PHGHmp3dmZwCR2TpNSG7TLi4lRIvHofBfQLBcHwIhSAoag6EYFh2F4ChJOGjZMAgAhxe0ghlHXtRiUBHR8ekOQaiupJkDD5uyyBggjIeQShYhwFxqGFk1MUibgXm8HIrt0De2sDAJAHttyLTYPHXwtdDQjy2LyWYkVcTe0mCAFOA8ADy7g1j9EuOacodJgRKkwJCZ25RQCMMcCQvEh0QxsA4QAdXUJoUa3DPhnXApBKA0FCT+Bzmufq90rCNB7sVf2f50BFRiOQyERdOG1C0SAQo+iXowgUDefQVjELkNZOyfqmi+LwUsfYjknJbGHTYbiCA8NDER0KFUBQ-RPEgihkAA)).

**UPDATE:**

To add some more context to your map you can add other shapes using geopandas as such:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
gdf = gpd.read_file('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-visualization/folium/master/tests/us-states.json', driver='GeoJSON')
gdf = gdf[gdf.id=='TX']

base = alt.Chart(gdf).mark_geoshape(
    stroke='gray', 
    fill=None
)

pts = alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(
    latitude='latitude',
    longitude='longitude',
    color='index'
)

base + pts
```

[image: context map]

Comment: Thank you for taking your time helping me with my problem. I'm able to understand altair a bit better now. I can't mark your question as `accepted` because the lack of a basemap makes this kind of geospatial plot rather useless, but thank you anyway!

Comment: Useless is a strong word. Many people have found Altair's geospatial vlsualization tools useful. I'd mark this answer as accepted, because it's the best possible answer for your question, which is how to visualize geospatial lat/long points in Altair, along with caveats about why the specific thing you're asking for is not possible right now, and pointers at how you might approach it.

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing this out. I understand your argumentation and marked this as the accepted answer. I didn't want to sound mean but it's hard for me to see the use of geospatial plots without any context information. It feels like a scatterplot without any information about the axis.

Comment: I feel your pain. I updated the answer how you could use geopandas in combination with the `mark_geoshape` to add some more context. Its not google maps like, but in many cases does it lead to an acceptable solution.